# Cannot deploy Bluemix Visual Recognition services

Tags: ibm-cloud, visual-recognition

I am a newbee and tried to deploy this [demo](https://hub.jazz.net/deploy/index.html?repository=https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/visual-recognition-nodejs:). I got the following errors:

```
Downloading artifacts...DOWNLOAD SUCCESSFUL
Target: https://api.ng.bluemix.net
FAILED
Error readingmanifest file:
yaml: line 3: mapping values are not allowed in this context
Finished: FAILED
Stage has no runtime information

Initial manifest.yml:
declared-services:
  visual-recognition-free
    label: watson_vision_combined
    plan: free
applications:
- services:
  - visual-recognition-free
  name: visual-recognition-demo
  command: npm start
  path: .
  memory: 512M
```

Due to errors I changed it:

```
declared-services:
  visual-recognition-free:
    label: watson_vision_combined
    plan: free
applications:
- name: visual-recognition-demo
  command: npm start
  path: .
  memory: 512M
services:
  - visual-recognition-free
```

Clicked on "Deploy the App from Workspace".

```
Deploy failed: An unknown error occurred.
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is related to the `manifest.yml` syntax. Currently, the `manifest.yml` file is defined as the following:

```
    ---
declared-services:
  visual-recognition-free
    label: watson_vision_combined
    plan: free
applications:
- services:
  - visual-recognition-free
  name: visual-recognition-demo
  command: npm start
  path: .
  memory: 512M
```

However, the `manifest.yml` should as the following:

```
    ---
declared-services:
  visual-recognition-free:
    label: watson_vision_combined
    plan: free
applications:
- services:
  - visual-recognition-free
  name: visual-recognition-demo
  command: npm start
  path: .
  memory: 512M
```

There should be a ":" at the end of the declared-services name "visual-recognition-free"

I have created a Github issue to get the manifest.yml file updated as well:

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/visual-recognition-nodejs/issues/193

In the interim, you can make the change with your project on Jazz Hub.

Comment: You're welcome Jens-Peter! I'm glad this helped. The Github issue has been fixed as well: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/visual-recognition-nodejs/issues/193

If possible, can you verify the answer resolved the issue.